# Hide pivot items efficiently

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, pivot-table

I have built a report based on a pivot table which feeds from a data table. The detail is quite long (tens of thousands of lines) and the user wishes the data to be summarized by a specific field so that he can drilldown only on totals that he is interested in.

I have currently succeeded by looping through all pivot items of all pivot tables for a specified field and hiding them. However, this is taking a significant amount of time ( > 15 min) to run. Is there any way to optimize this by using a different process or is there any option to do this task in bulk (through a setting or an option) which could be faster ?

Here is the function that gets called to do this task:

```
Sub groupByjrnl_id()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pi As PivotItem
    Dim pt As PivotTable

    Excel.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Excel.Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If Left(ws.Name, 3) = "rap" Then
            Excel.Application.StatusBar = "Groupement des jrnl_id " & ws.Name
            For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
                With pt.PivotFields("jrnl_id")
                    For Each pi In .PivotItems
                        pi.ShowDetail = False
                    Next pi
                End With
            Next pt
        End If
    Next ws
    Excel.Application.StatusBar = ""

    Excel.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Excel.Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

I am using Excel 2007. Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: instead of enumerating through the pivotfield's pivot items you simply use the `.ShowDetail` property of the pivotfield itself e.g.:

Replace

```
For Each pi In .PivotItems
    pi.ShowDetail = False
Next pi
```

With

```
.ShowDetail = False
```

Comment: Thanks. I had already found it and was about to post the answer. This is exactly what I used and it works in a second or less. Great !

Comment: sorry for pipping you to the post ;). Glad it's sorted either way.